# Count of products whose cost is greater than 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, wc

I have file

```
Product Cost
a       10
b       20
c       30
```

I want to count no of products whose cost is greater than 10.
I have used:

```
awk '{$2>10}' myfile | wc -l
```

but its not functioning — I get the result `0` instead of `2` which I am expecting.  What's wrong?

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  What result are you getting?  What did you expect?  (_First pass:_ I expect you're seeing the answer `2` — is that what you're seeing?)  (_Second pass:_  Oops — misread the code; see my answer.)

Comment: I am actually getting 0:(

Comment: You should add the extra information to the question.  "It isn't working" (or "functioning") is [NBG](http://www.acronymfinder.com/NBG.html) as a diagnosis.  You should always explain what you're getting, and explain what you think you should be getting.  Also, if you haven't got a sentence that ends with a question mark, you've not asked a question — this is a question and answer site, and you should always ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

You have a condition wrapped in braces; you don't want that:

```
awk '$2 > 10' myfile | wc -l
```

As it was, the condition generated 0 or 1, but there was no print, so `wc -l` counted 0 (because `awk` produced no output).

Also, as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556310/15168), you can have `awk` do the counting without using `wc`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `wc`, you can do the counting in `awk`. But the main issue is that the condition test needs to be outside the braces (or inside the braces and in an `if` statement).

```
awk '$2 > 10 { count++ } END {print count}' myfile
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{if($2 > 10} myfile | wc -1
```

I think this might be the solution, give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Unbalanced quotes...and unbalanced parentheses...and no action.

Comment: Your braces aren't matched

Comment: You left out the body of the `if`